# Reacts this.props.children in vue.js component

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vue-component

React has something like `this.props.children`: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html

Does Vue.js have also some similar to access the child-elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your requirement：

Using slot is a right way to pass a custom component into the child component, when you are in the parent component level.

But why doesn't it work? Because in Vue 1.0, it uses the browser to parse the template, not virtual DOM. Browser-parsing has a problem: *some HTML elements have restrictions on what elements can appear inside them.*

see Vue1.0 Doc: [vue1.0 - components - template parsing](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Template-Parsing)

And you happen to make that mistake.

This is a limitation in Vue1.0, you have to write some Directives to do them.

But in Vue 2.0, things have changed, the template-parsing became a virtual-dom implement. You can pass any DOM elements into slot.

I try your link in last comment with Vue 2.0, it works.

Just change the External Resources to https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.1/dist/vue.js

Comment: awesome - good decision by vuejs to switch to this virtual dom engine...

Answer (score 27):

The equivalent to `this.props.children` in Vue is `<slot />`.

**Example**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

See http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js has `this.$children`, which also gives you an array of child components

http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-children

If you want to reference specific components, you might want to use [v-ref](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-ref) and `this.$refs`

Comment: I created this fiddle with an example - can you find what's wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/kt8urx7d/1/

I doesn't render the <options> in the <select>

Comment: oh, seeing what you are tryintg to do I realize you actually want something else - slots: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Comment: Its strange.. the slot works with the some-text component, but not with the select: https://jsfiddle.net/n0osk4om/2/